# Problem with OpenXML Library in C#: Numbers Not Recognized in Excel File Creation

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, number-formatting

I'm trying to create an Excel file using C# and I'm using the OpenXML library for this purpose. However, I've encountered a problem where numbers are not being recognized in the number format, resulting in errors as shown in the image below.

[image]

I'm sharing the part where I add data to the cell below:

```
 // The text here actually contains a number, like this: "1"
 CellValue cellValue = new CellValue(text);
 cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
 cell.CellValue = cellValue;
```

Comment: Use the correct value type, eg int or decimal, not `string`. Your code stores a string with a `Number` format instead of an actual number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct type instead of text :

```
cell.DataType = CellValues.Number;
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(1);
```

Numbers in Excel aren't just text with the `Number` style. They're stored as strongly-type values in the XML file itself, ensuring there's never any confusion between `3.21` and `3,21` due to localized parsing.

The [CellValue constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue.-ctor?view=openxml-3.0.1) accepts different value types, including `int`, `DateTime`, `Decimal`, `Boolean` etc